# I have write permissions on a file, but I can't use the "unlink()" function to delete it

Tags: php, unlink, ubuntu-server

I've Googled around a bit, and can't find any answer that works for me. I'm trying to unlink a file, but nothing happens and no errors appear (display_errors() stopped the page from loading). The code is below. Thanks!

```
 chdir("/var/www/lib.techtri.be/");
 unlink("/var/www/lib.techtri.be/R1Count.txt");
```

**Edit:** I know the chdir isn't needed, that's just for the later parts in the file.

Comment: what are the exact permissions for the `/var/www/lib.techtri.be/` dir? The script you say you have write permission from, is the same as the one you are trying to unlink the file from?

Answer (score 4):

You can only delete a file if you also have write permission on the directory containing it.

```
% mkdir foo
% touch foo/bar
% chmod u-w foo
% rm foo/bar
rm foo/bar: Permission denied
```